# Execute shell command from AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to execute a shell command to migrate from the AWS lambda. The idea is that whenever we need to run the migration, we will call the lambda via AWS CLI. I am unable to make it run. The command to run migration never gets executed and it's always response with null. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have :

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const { okResponse, errorResponse } = require('./response');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    exec("node ./node_modules/db-migrate/bin/db-migrate up --config=./database.json", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        return okResponse(200, 'Migration successfully.');
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put `await` before your command execution line `await exec("node ./node_modules/db-migrate/bin/db-migrate up`

Comment: Also how are you calling the function from CLI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that because you are using [async lambda handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) your function finishes before `exec` has a chance to even run. Therefore, you could use `promise`, as shown in the linked docs, to solve this issue.

An example would be:

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const { okResponse, errorResponse } = require('./response');

exports.handler = async (event) => {


    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   
        exec("node ./node_modules/db-migrate/bin/db-migrate up --config=./database.json", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
                return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            return okResponse(200, 'Migration successfully.');
          })
    })

   return promise
}
```

Please note that I haven't run the code, and further changes may be required to make it work correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I already solved it. And yes, a Promise was what I needed. Your answer matches the solution. I am going to accept your answer. Thank you for your time. Cheers